# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:react-native-hms-site]

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

While integrating react-native-hms-site sdk in the Android studio, build failed due to below error

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:react-native-hms-site]
```

library might be using APIs not available in 16.

Answer (score 17):

Change minSdkVersion to 19 in the project build.gradle file
"minSdkVersion = 19"

Comment: Can you answer why ? My project was working fine till yesterday